# Responsive Design for an existing web site

Tags: responsive-design

What is the best practice for creating a mobile/tablet site from an existing website?

I have been researching responsive webdesign but it seems that i would need to recreate the site from the ground up as the site is badly tagged and designed.

I was thinking of creating a separate site for mobile/tablets that uses responsive design but show the old site for people browsing on desktops.

What do you think is the best solution? Have you had any good/bad experiences with responsive web design?

Answer (score 1):

I [suggest](http://foundation.zurb.com) which is a great framework to RWD (responsive web design). It has support from cell phones to tablets of wide screen. [This is a case study](http://www.flite.com/) about the framework.

Comment: Yes! Foundation is licensed under the MIT open source license, more info in: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/faq.html